# Is there a way to download from Firebase storage as a file?

Tags: firebase, http, flutter, dart, download

In my application I am attempting to download from Firebase as a file object so I may use the File.copy method to save the image or video locally as a file. Is there anyway to download from Firebase as a generic File object?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), you should be able to download the file.